# Notify app when connection state changes in background

Tags: ios, swift, sip, voip, pjsip

When app goes in background seems there is no way to use `Reachability` module to make possible app to be notified about:

- Device is disconnected from current network then connects back.
- Device is disconnected from current network and connects to a new network.
- Device receives a new IP.

These events are important, app must update it's location otherwise user will miss calls, etc.

**Update:**

App is using `setKeepAliveTimeout` to trigger each 10 minutes a registration process which will update location, but this is too long.

Comment: Have you implemented the VoIP background mode? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13

Comment: yes I did, but I use reachability notifications instead of SCNetworkReachabilityRef callback method.

Comment: This (http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/102712223177/correctly-implementing-network-reachability-on-ios) article may be useful for you.